# While loop Ignores If Statement

Tags: python

I am generating 'key values' that will help the functions encrypt and decrypt do their job.

The 'if ans == e' statement is being run and does return a output but ignores the 'k = True' statement, causing the program to go in a infinite loop on the encrypt function. Does anyone know why it is doing this?

```
ans = input("Would you like to decrypt or encrypt your message (e/d)? ")
key = Generate.gen.keys(self)

k = False
while not k:

    if ans == "e":
        encrypt(key[0], key[1])
        k = True

    if ans == "d":
        decrypt(key[0], key[2])
        k = True

    else:
        k = False


def encrypt(n, e):
    output = []
    plain_text = input("Please enter message: ")
    raw = list(plain_text)
    print(raw)

    for char in raw:
        ascii_val = ord(char)
        pub = ascii_val ** e % n
        print(pub)
        output.append(pub)
    print(output)
```

Many thanks, 
Callum

Comment: You probably want `elif` instead of the second `if`: If `ans` was `"e"`, `k` will be set to `True`, after which we check for `ans` to be `"d"`, which it isn't, therefore we go to the `else` branch and set `k`  back to `False`.

Comment: Why is there even a `while` loop? You should just check `if ans == 'e'` or `if ans == 'd'`. What happens if it's not? You will have an infinite loop as you're not allowing to change `ans`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ans == "e":
    encrypt(key[0], key[1])
    k = True
if ans == "d":
    decrypt(key[0], key[2])
    k = True  
else:
    k = False
```

If you read your code, your logic is as follows.

1. If ans == 'e' set k=true
2. If ans == 'd' set k=true

   1. If ans != 'd' set k=false

If ans == 'e' is true, ans cannot == 'd' and so the else case is run which sets k back to false.

**Consider using an elif for ans == 'd'**
`elif ans == 'd':`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> k = False
> while not k:
>     if ans == "e":
>         # ...
>         k = True
> ```

If `ans == "e"` is true, then `k = True` will indeed be executed.

But then, the next `if`/`else` statement comes.

> ```
>     if ans == "d":
>         # ...
>     else:
>         k = False
> ```

If `ans` was `"e"`, it will not simultaneously be `"d"`. Therefore, the `else` part will be executed which sets `k` back to `False`.

You need to use `elif ans == "d"` so that this part is skipped `if ans == "e"` was true before.